# MySQL 8 ST_GeomFromGeoJSON is throwing longitude out of range error

Tags: geometry, geospatial, geojson, mysql-8.0

I have a table with polygons stored as geojson.

```
CREATE TABLE `location_boundaries` (
   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
   `geo_json` JSON NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `geom` GEOMETRY NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I have geojson multipolygon for asia as follows in the table:

```
{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-168.25, 77.7], [-180, 77.7], [-180, 58.1], [-168.25, 58.1], [-168.25, 77.7]]], [[[39.6908, 84.52666], [180, 84.38487], [180, 26.27883], [142.084541, 22.062707], [130.147, 3.608598], [141.1373, -1.666358], [141.0438, -9.784795], [130.2645, -10.0399], [118.2545, -13.01165], [102.7975, -8.388008], [89.50451, -11.1417], [61.62511, -9.103512], [51.62645, 12.54865], [44.20775, 11.6786], [39.78016, 16.56855], [31.60401, 31.58641], [33.27769, 34.00057], [34.7674, 34.85347], [35.72423, 36.32686], [36.5597, 37.66439], [44.1053, 37.98438], [43.01638, 41.27191], [41.28304, 41.41274], [36.26378, 44.40772], [36.61315, 45.58723], [37.48493, 46.80924], [38.27497, 47.61317], [39.56164, 48.43141], [39.77264, 50.58891], [39.6908, 84.52666]]]]}
```

When I run the following

```
 UPDATE location_boundaries SET geom = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geo_json) where id = 6255147
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Longitude -180.000000 is out of range in function st_geomfromgeojson. It must be within (-180.000000, 180.000000].")
```

What's going on. All this was working fine in mysql 5.7 yet in mysql 8 everything has messed up?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Having the same problem after upgrading from 5.7 to 8.0.20

Comment: @MSquared in Mysql 8 they've changed the order of (long,lat) to (lat,long). I also revalidated my geojson by downloading Qgis and found a lot of my geojson was invalid. Refer to the following for more details: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242001/mysql-8-st-geomfromtext-giving-error-latitude-out-of-range-in-function-st-geomfr